# Get top and left offsets of element cross-browser

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to get an element's left and top offsets in a way that will work crossbrowser. My current code is this:

```
function getOffsets(elem){
  if(typeof elem.getBoundingClientRect!==undefined){
   var rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
   return {top: rect.top, left: rect.left};
  } else {
    return {top: elem.offsetTop, left: elem.offsetLeft};
  }
}
```

How can I improve it to work for most edge cases? I want my function to work in all browsers.

Comment: edge the browser? =P wich ones are you aiming?

Comment: @aloMalbarez I want my function to work in all browsers.

Comment: you might need to account for `document.body.scrollTop` and `document.body.scrollLeft` IE 8+ IIRC

Comment: @aloMalbarez How would I do that? Please explain to me. I'm sorry, but my Javascript is not very good.

Comment: maybe a JS guru can explain it better than me, `getBoundingClientRect` gives the offset relative to a viewport, so if you have a scrolling viewport you have to add the number of pixels the content has been scrolled